# react scripts build generate new hash even if the code not changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hash

I build react app without create-react-app (without eject).
I want to generate new hash every build if the code not change (because cache issue).
I installed react-app-rewired for using config overloads and change package.json to

```
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
```

in config-overrides.js I'm trying to create new hash for each build (minified, css, js,styled and etc) but not sure I do it in right way

```
require('dotenv').config();
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config, env) {
    console.log('outputconfig before', config.output);
    const buildHash = uniqid();
    config.output.filename = `static/js/[name].${buildHash}.js`;
    config.output.chunkFilename = `static/js/[name].${buildHash}.chunk.js`;
    console.log('outputs config', config.output);
    return config;
  },
};
```

when I deploy it to production it looks like the hash build is the same if the code has not changes.. not sure if I configure the config-overloads.js right, maybe I need to add webpack or something not sure.[image]

I want every build to generate new unique name to js, css and html files.

Comment: Hash is generate from the source code. Same code will always generate the same hash, it's not random characters.

Comment: yes I know, I want to force it to generate a new one, even if the code has not changed.. no needs hash, it can be unique number using uniqueId package

Comment: what are you trying to do? this seems like an xy problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is the same, if you did not change anything in the codebase, webpack will ALWAYS produce the same hash. This is the main property of a `hash function`. So you have to somehow always change the codebase. To achieve this you can write to a `js` file and import it in app.js so webpack will see that file's input has changed. In your `webpack.config.js`

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");

const content = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString("hex");
const value = JSON.stringify(content);
// we have to write a valid javascript
fs.writeFile("src/test.js", `export const a=${value}`, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

this `test.js` has no effect on your code. So you could safely import in `app.js`

```
import "./test.js";
```

If you dont import it will not work. Because webpack will read only imported code.

in webpack.config.js i defined the filename like this

```
output: {
    filename: "[name].[hash].js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
```

every time I  run `npm run build` it creates a different hash. Proof of work:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to do it without to write every time? maybe the way I did with create unique id?

Comment: @Manspof changes in webpack.config did not produce a new hash. even i wrote it to test.js without importing, did not work neither. you have to somehow make sure that there is a change in your code base and webpack should detect it

Comment: ok, I don't have webpack.config.js, I have config-overrides.js, can I write it there?

Comment: @Manspof yeah. it should not be issue. try it